# How can we get up to date Google Maps component on MonoTouch?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.ios

looking in the [Xamarin Component Store for Google Maps](http://components.xamarin.com/view/googlemapsios/) gives us a component at revision 1.3.1.1. I'd like to help with getting more up to date revisions published into the component store.

How can I help make this happen?

Comment: Hello, as @Stephane Delcroix pointed out you can get a more recent version here https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/GoogleMaps the Component in the store comes from the same place (I am the maintainer) I have not updated the component in the store due to we need more testing of it before we release it see https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/issues/159

Answer (score 1):

There's a binding for google-maps `1.4.3` available in the monotouch-bindings at https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/GoogleMaps

You can build it from there.

I'm not 100% sure both API are matching, be as they're both bindings for the same native library, they should be very close.

Comment: Indeed, Google changed some parts of their API but is not that bad, we are working on it at the moment to overcome some issues with the new update

Answer (score 1):

Hello New version of Google Maps is live in the store, check it out

http://components.xamarin.com/view/googlemapsios/

Alex